# What is the correct way to do two-way data binding on android?

Tags: android, android-databinding

i made a simple hello world for 2 way data binding and seams works perfectly (when write on editext, the textview update automatically), but all code found online like official documentation has much more code and complications like https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way

this is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public String pippo;
    public Boolean visible = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);

    }
}



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="pippo"
            type="String" />

        <variable
            name="visible"
            type="Boolean" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@={pippo}" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{pippo}"
            android:visibility="@{visible ? android.view.View.VISIBLE: android.view.View.GONE}" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="@={visible}" />
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

In particular documentation use this things but seams useless:

- BaseObservable
- @Bindable
- code to Avoids infinite loops
- notifyPropertyChanged

so, what wrong or missing with my code?

Comment: basically without these useless things, you cant actually get the superpowers of data binding. BaseObservable has notify characteristics and callbacks & bindable annotation makes it possible to react to changes done

Comment: in my example textview change text when write in edittext. what's missing?

Comment: it does because the attribute android:text has built-in support but let's say you want to create a feature where you have to change the color of icon-based on edit text is empty or not you won't be able to do it unless you use BaseObservable, Bindable & notify property changed. Two-way data binding won't work

Comment: all attempts i tried works without all that things, this is the reason why i can't understand why this is needed. can you specify a single case doesen't work without all that things?

Comment: sure I have already given you one, just try to play with visibility using two-way data binding. Like, let's say you have a boolean isVisible and you have to hide and show based on true or false. Two-way data binding won't work but using BaseObservable, Bindable you can make it work.

Comment: edited example with our suggestion but continue working :(

Comment: data binding library by default, looks for methods named `set[Attribute]` and `get[Attribute]` (for two-way) if they exist (with appropriate input types) they will be used for binding. besides, for two-way a method that gets a listener is needed to notify it about changes. for built-in views they are implemented. those documentations are provided if you want to add support for your custom view or custom attributes. so it can be very clean and simple if there are some functions already available or be implemented easily as you see in docs.

Comment: This has perfect sense, but why it has never mentioned on official documentation? Imho this make difference from benefit to detriment

Comment: Good question! and we need detailed explanations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the two-way data binding you need to create class that extends from `BaseObservable`, annotate getters with `@Bindable` and call `notifyPropertyChanged` in your setters as below:

```
public class Person extends BaseObservable {

    private String name;

    Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Bindable
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.name);
    }

}
```

Then pass this class as a databinding layout variable of type `Person`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="person"
            type="com.example.android......Person" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@={person.name}" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{person.name}" />
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Note: change the class path in the `type` attribute.

and then set this layout variable in your activity with `setPerson()`

```
public class ExampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_example);

        ActivityExampleBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_example);

        mActivityMainBinding.setPerson(new Person(""));
    }
}
```

Comment: my example works, when i write in edittext, the textview update with current new text. what's the benefit in your code that is more complicated?

Comment: @Xan yeah it works but for complex objects it won't, you need to create a custom `BaseObservable` though

Comment: all attempts i tried works without all that things, this is the reason why i can't understand why this is needed. can you specify a single case doesen't work without all that things?

Comment: @Xan for instance, if you have some integer and you want to map its physcial range of values (say temperature range) to say a spinner, you might need some intermediate conversions to match the spinner range, here you need to do that in setMyInteger() .. another example if you have an API response with multiple data that you want to two-way databinding them, it would be easy to combine all in a single POJO BaseObservable

Comment: edited my example with checkbox and boolean visibile variable, but seams continue working

Answer (score 6):

The most simple way to me is using  @={variable} instead @{variable}

You can see it in:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@={viewModel.name}"
    android:inputType="text" />
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: This won't work without observable for two-way data-binding

Comment: @Zain Of course it works