# Android Two-Way Data Binding with Double (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding, android-databinding

I have a `ViewModel` class defined as follows:

```
class StockLoadTaskModel : ViewModel() {
    ....
    ....
 
    var d: Double = 10.0
}
```

That is bound to the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    
    <data>
        <import type="android.view.View" />
        <import type="it.kfi.lorikeetmobile.extras.Converter" alias="Converter"/
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="it.kfi.lorikeetmobile.stock.models.StockLoadTaskModel" />
        <variable
            name="view"
            type="it.kfi.lorikeetmobile.stock.ui.movements.StockLoadTaskFragment
    </data>
    
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    
        ...
    
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp">
    
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/et_code"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/hint_et_item_code"
                android:text="@={viewModel.itemCode}" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp">
    
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/et_quantity"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:text="@={Converter.doubleToString(d)}"
                android:hint="@string/quantity" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp">
    
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/et_note"
                android:lines="3"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:overScrollMode="ifContentScrolls"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/hint_et_note"
                android:text="@={viewModel.selectedItem.detail.note}"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
        
        ...
    </LinearLayout>
```

And I have also the following `Converter` object:

```
object Converter {
    
    @JvmStatic
    @InverseMethod("stringToDouble")
    fun doubleToString(value: Double?): String? {
    
        if (value == null) {
            return null
        }
        return DecimalFormat(ClientConfiguration.currentConfig.decimalFormat).format(value)
    }
    
    @JvmStatic
    fun stringToDouble(value: String?): Double? {
    
        if (value == null) {
            return null
        }
        val v = DecimalFormat(ClientConfiguration.currentConfig.decimalFormat).parse(value)
        return v.toDouble()
    }
}
```

If I set: `android:text="@={Converter.doubleToString(d)}"` (two-way databinding), in the `EditText` with id `et_quantity` I get the following error:

```
...error: cannot find symbol
```

If I change it into a one-way databinding like: `android:text="@{Converter.doubleToString(d)}"`, it works. It looks like the binding manager is not able to recognize the inverse method.

Can anybody help me? Thank you.

Comment: use `MutableLiveData` for two way databinding, `val d = MutableLiveData(10.0)`

Comment: Originally instead of "d" there was a Room entity with a quantity field of type Double stored in a MutableLiveData. It doesn't work either.

Comment: And anyway, "val d = MutableLiveData(10.0)", doesn't work.... as I was expecting

Comment: Strange, it works for me. Change `Converter.doubleToString(d)` to `Converter.doubleToString(viewModel.d)` also you forgot `>` after `alias="Converter"/`

Comment: There is, it just wasn't copied in the clipboard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Why the error happens?

When you define two-way data binding like you have in your example `android:text="@={Converter.doubleToString(d)}"` the question is: what function/object will receive data that you get back **passed from** `EditText` as user types data in? Should data be passed to `Converter.doubleToString` or maybe some other static function of `Converter`? Maybe to the result of `Converter.doubleToString(d)` or to `d` variable?

**You must be precise.**

You expect it is `d`, the compiler expects it is the result of `Converter.doubleToString(d)`. Actually, neither will work.

Another issue is that `EditText` does operate with characters. It knows nothing about double, int, float, byte, short, boolean or anything else that is not a string.

It means that in order to implement two-way data binding your source:

- must **return value** of type String;
- must be assignable.

#### How to fix the issue?

Android architecture components introduce us with [`ObservableField`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ObservableField) class. There are ready to use `ObservableBoolean`, `ObservableChar`, `ObservableFloat` and a few others. *If you open the link from the previous sentence you should see all of the classes `Observable...` on the left pane.*

There is no `ObservableString` but `ObservableField` accepts a generic type. So you can define a variable that is a part of data binding to be `ObservableField<String>("defaultValueHere")`.

So what you should have is:

```
class StockLoadTaskModel : ViewModel() {
    ....
    ....
    var d: Double = 10.0
    var dataBindingVariable = ObservableField<String>(d.toString())
}
```

The `dataBindingVariable` will always return you the contents of an `EditText` you bound it to. You can get that value and safely convert to double.

```
class StockLoadTaskModel : ViewModel() {
    ....
    ....
    var d: Double = 10.0
    var dataBindingVariable = 
        object: ObservableField<String>(d.toString()) {
            override fun set(value: String?) {
                super.set(value)
                // a value has been set
                d = value.toDoubleOrNull() ?: d
            }
        }
}
```

Layout declaration will look like that for input field:

```
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/et_quantity"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:text="@={viewModel.dataBindingVariable}"
                android:hint="@string/quantity" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

And there will be no need for `object Converter`.

*There is another way of doing two-way data binding I'm not talking about here because it was already answered. [Here it is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61562689/7210237).*

Comment: Hi Jenea. I gave you the check and an Up-Vote, even if the answer was not exactly what I was expecting. I mean, in the end I could have created a MutableLiveData with a String value, and then switching type and assigning in the observer . That would have done exactly the same job. The Converter is much more useful and elegant (I could have reused it in all my Models, without adding extra code).... but that's it. Thank you very much for your precious help.